# Copying file with spaces on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, google-chrome

I'm trying in a shell script to copy a predefined set of Chrome bookmarks to the location where Chrome keeps them on a Mac (`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`).  In the script I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
bookmarks_dir="$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default"
cp -v "bookmarks/Bookmarks" "$bookmarks_dir"
```

But when I run this I get:

```
cp: /Users/aparkin/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default: No such file or directory
```

If I copy & paste the path in the error message above and do the cp by hand:

```
cp -v bookmarks/Bookmarks /Users/aparkin/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

It copies fine, so the directory does in fact exist.  It seems to be the space in the path that's tripping things up.

What am I missing?  I thought if a variable is enclosed in quotes that spaces in filenames no longer cause problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `\` in the `$bookmarks_dir` definition. It's being treated as a literal `\`: if you did an `$echo bookmarks_dir` you'd see it.

The `\` is only useful if you won't put quotes around the string. So,

```
bookmarks_dir=$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

would also work.